# monkey test java.io.filenotfoundexception

Tags: java, android, monkey

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.forward.test/files/1458096313000.stacktrace: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:643)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:159)
    at org.acra.CrashReportPersister.load(SourceFile:65)
    at org.acra.BaseCrashReportDialog.sendCrash(SourceFile:72)
    at org.acra.CrashReportDialog.onClick(SourceFile:141)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
```

how to know the exception thrown where in my code? from the log, may guess the file is not created, but how to locate which file

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException says `/data/data/com.forward.test/files/1458096313000.stacktrace`. I would investigate especially the doubled `data`.

Comment: The doubled `data` is part of the normal Android filesystem structure, there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

The file not found is:
/data/data/com.forward.test/files/1458096313000.stacktrace

It seems like it's originating from your acra crash reporter.

It's unable to open the above mentioned stack trace file.